# 6" open HVAC supply open in floor cavity

Tags: hvac

While doing some remodel in my basement I noticed a 6" supply run just left open in my floor cavity:

[image]

I have verified that there is no other pipe any where close to which this should be attached.  The supply trunk is just to the right of the picture.  All vents still have airflow.

I live in Utah in the US.  The supply and return are all run in and suspended from the floor joist between the main floor and basement.  The basement was finished when I bought the home.

My question is:  Is this normal practice for some reason?  Should I cap it?